# Make a script work within a page

Tags: javascript, html, editor

I have this code from a third party, with no instructions whatsoever, and I can't manage to make it work within a WordPress page. It's supposed to show a carousel of items.

Can this even go inside the page editor?

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='jquery-style-css' href='https://scd01.bcnshop.com/ca/widgets/generate-css/1815/4150.css' type='text/css' />

<script src="https://scd01.bcnshop.com/ca/widgets/generate-js/1815/4150.js"></script>
```

Any help on how to implement this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please show us how you've enqueued this script to your WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

I think both external CSS & JavaScript files should be added to your active theme functions.php file into function which implements action wp_enqueue_scripts.

It should looks like example code below:

```
<?php
// ...
function themename_enqueue_scripts() {
    // ...
    wp_enqueue_style('themename-slider-style', '//scd01.bcnshop.com/ca/widgets/generate-css/1815/4150.css', false );
    wp_enqueue_script('themename-slider-js', '//scd01.bcnshop.com/ca/widgets/generate-js/1815/4150.js', array('jquery') );
    // ...
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'themename_enqueue_scripts' );
```

Comment: This looks like it might work, but I'm really noob here so I'd really appreciate a little more guidance. After adding this to functions.php, how can I call this action from within the page editor? And could you please explain what does "slider" have to do with it? Thank you!

Comment: @ireth92, these two lines are adding required CSS & JavaScript files to your page.

Comment: You should also have JQuery JavaScript library loaded before javascript to make slider work. Your HTML editor should also have div with id="tbcn_widget4150" on page where slider will be displayed